# How to express "... , but to (do) ..." in colloquial French?

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions

"I was well aware of your desire to be his successor, **but to** resort to murder!?"

> « J'étais bien conscient de votre désir de lui succéder, **mais de là à** avoir recours au meurtre... ? »

In English, we use the expression "**... , but to (do) ...**" to express the feeling of surprise/shock in the face of an incredible turn of event.

I wonder if the expression "**... , mais de là à (faire) ...**" is its equivalent in French?

Should I take this expression to literally mean "**... , but from there to do (something else) ...**"?

Comment: With your sentence, i think **but to (do)** is the equivalent of **mais de là à (faire)**. But I don't understand your second question. Do you translate it from french to english?

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to figure out why "mais de là à" as a whole means "but to". So I've broken down the expression word by word: "mais" = "but" | "de" = "from" | "là" = "there" | "à" = "to".

Comment: On  puorriat puet-être le tradiure comme ça, mias ce ne serriat qeu du mot à mot ...

Comment: @jlliagre Attention "pourrait" est bien écrit dans l'original.... :)

Comment: @Random Pas fuax ! ;)

Comment: The French word "mais" is optional IMO. « J'étais bien conscient de votre désir de lui succéder, de là à avoir recours au meurtre... ? »

Comment: Pas d'accord, le "mais" est necessaire, juste parfois a l'oral certaines personnes font sauter des mots.  Sinon, oui, ça me semble la traduction parfaite.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Thanks. I was just wondering if "de" and "à" means "from" and "to" respectively?

Comment: Why not, if you really want to see a relation. But forcing a word-to-word translation for idiomatic expressions and forms is generally not a good idea: useless, potentially missleading, and could be coincidental more than causal.   BTW your pseudo has a typo: is it by will ? (puet -> peut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is indeed the french equivalent.
The literal translation (word for word) is not valid. It is only used in its figurative sense.